# Server and Client Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, server, client

i am trying to connect two different cell phones. one acts as a server while the second acts as a client. I tried to do this:

For Server:
MainActivity.java

```html
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Thread Thread1 = null;
    TextView tvIP, tvPort;
    TextView tvMessages;
    EditText etMessage;
    Button btnSend;
    public static String SERVER_IP = "";
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 8080;
    String message;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvIP = findViewById(R.id.tvIP);
        tvPort = findViewById(R.id.tvPort);
        tvMessages = findViewById(R.id.tvMessages);
        etMessage = findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
        btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        try {
            SERVER_IP = getLocalIpAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
        Thread1.start();
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                message = etMessage.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!message.isEmpty()) {
                    new Thread(new Thread3(message)).start();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private String getLocalIpAddress() throws UnknownHostException {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        assert wifiManager != null;
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        int ipInt = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
        return InetAddress.getByAddress(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(ipInt).array()).getHostAddress();
    }
    private PrintWriter output;
    private BufferedReader input;
    class Thread1 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvMessages.setText("Not connected");
                        tvIP.setText("IP: " + SERVER_IP);
                        tvPort.setText("Port: " + String.valueOf(SERVER_PORT));
                    }
                });
                try {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tvMessages.setText("Connected\n");
                        }
                    });
                    new Thread(new Thread2()).start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private class Thread2 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    final String message = input.readLine();
                    if (message != null) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                tvMessages.append("client:" + message + "\n");
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
                        Thread1.start();
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class Thread3 implements Runnable {
        private String message;
        Thread3(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            output.write(message);
            output.flush();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tvMessages.append("server: " + message + "\n");
                    etMessage.setText("");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```html
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                android:layout_height = "match_parent"
                android:layout_margin = "16dp"
                tools:context = ".MainActivity">
    <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/tvIP"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance = "@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
    <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/tvPort"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_below = "@+id/tvIP"
            android:textAppearance = "@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
    <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/tvConnectionStatus"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_below = "@+id/tvPort"
            android:textAppearance = "@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
    <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/tvMessages"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_above = "@+id/etMessage"
            android:layout_below = "@+id/tvConnectionStatus"
            android:inputType = "textMultiLine"
            android:textAppearance = "@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
    <EditText
            android:id = "@+id/etMessage"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_above = "@+id/btnSend"
            android:hint = "Enter Message"
            android:inputType = "text" />
    <Button
            android:id = "@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
            android:text = "SEND" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and ANdroidManifest.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.serverapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

while for Client, this is the code
MainActivity.java

```html
package com.example.clientapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Thread Thread1 = null;
    EditText etIP, etPort;
    TextView tvMessages;
    EditText etMessage;
    Button btnSend;
    String SERVER_IP;
    int SERVER_PORT;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etIP = findViewById(R.id.etIP);
        etPort = findViewById(R.id.etPort);
        tvMessages = findViewById(R.id.tvMessages);
        etMessage = findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
        btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        Button btnConnect = findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
        btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tvMessages.setText("");
                SERVER_IP = etIP.getText().toString().trim();
                SERVER_PORT = Integer.parseInt(etPort.getText().toString().trim());
                Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
                Thread1.start();
            }
        });
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = etMessage.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!message.isEmpty()) {
                    new Thread(new Thread3(message)).start();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private PrintWriter output;
    private BufferedReader input;
    class Thread1 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket;
            try {
                socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
                output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvMessages.setText("Connected\n");
                    }
                });
                new Thread(new Thread2()).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    class Thread2 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    final String message = input.readLine();
                    if (message != null) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                tvMessages.append("server: " + message + "\n");
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
                        Thread1.start();
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class Thread3 implements Runnable {
        private String message;
        Thread3(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            output.write(message);
            output.flush();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tvMessages.append("client: " + message + "\n");
                    etMessage.setText("");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```html
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width = "match_parent"
                android:layout_height = "match_parent"
                android:layout_margin = "16dp"
                tools:context = ".MainActivity">
    <EditText
            android:id = "@+id/etIP"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:hint = "IP-Address"
            android:inputType = "text" />
    <EditText
            android:id = "@+id/etPort"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_below = "@+id/etIP"
            android:hint = "Port No"
            android:inputType = "number" />
    <Button
            android:id = "@+id/btnConnect"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_below = "@+id/etPort"
            android:layout_gravity = "center"
            android:layout_marginTop = "16dp"
            android:text = "Connect To Server" />
    <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/tvMessages"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_above = "@+id/etMessage"
            android:layout_below = "@+id/btnConnect"
            android:inputType = "textMultiLine"
            android:textAppearance = "@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
    <EditText
            android:id = "@+id/etMessage"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_above = "@+id/btnSend"
            android:hint = "Enter Message"
            android:inputType = "text" />
    <Button
            android:id = "@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
            android:text = "SEND" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and AndroidManifest.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.clientapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

With these two applications I can connect server and client but if the applications are in the same device.

my question is, how to make the two applications work on different devices and not on the same?

Comment: Are the devices using wifi of same router! Or using mobile connection? If your server app is on an Android device using mobile connection then no client can connect as the mobile provider blocks incoming connections. Using wifi is ok. You did not tell your setup.

Comment: `SERVER_IP = etIP.getText().toString().trim()` Nobody knows which ip you use. And you did not tell.

Comment: And`getText()` already returns a `String`, so calling `toString()` on it is otiose.